# Javascript - "Cannot read property 'closingEls' of undefined" and "Script error."

Tags: javascript, browser

I get the following errors in the JavaScript console with no file source hint:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closingEls' of undefined

and

> Script error

These errors prevent my page from running scripts and I don't understand what kind of errors they are.

I tried searching what 'closingEls' is, but no luck. I don't know what type of tags I need to put in this question due to the vague nature of these errors.

**Edit 1:** Please, before you say show us the code, read the question! my scripts do not run in the first place. And this errors does not come out of the site's scripts, it comes from the user's agent trying to load the page.

**Edit 2:** Please, advice a way to deal with the users having this errors and can not load the page successfully. I would consider this very helpful, constructive and question-related.

Comment: Where's the code? Please show that so we can help.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: accessing a property of something which isn't there. Well without seeing any code it is not easy to answer a solution to this.

Comment: Are you saying that you created the JS on the page and don't know of any closingEl variable? Then it's probably injected code. But it sounds from your question that you are trying to decipher someone else's page.

Comment: @HaLeiVi You are clever but the answer is NO.

Comment: @HaLeiVi These are errors that occur on few users of mine.

Comment: I have the same error popping in our bug reporting with this extra indication: window.Mindspark_.closingEls();

Answer (score 8):

The "Script error." happens in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome when an exception violates the browser's same-origin policy - i.e. when the error occurs in a script that's hosted on a domain other than the domain of the current page.

Can read more over here:

- http://blog.errorception.com/2012/04/script-error-on-line-0.html
- https://blog.sentry.io/2016/05/17/what-is-script-error.html

Regarding "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closingEls' of undefined" Even I'm getting them in my Sentry log, and I don't know how to fix them. I think these errors are from Browser Extensions trying to add their own script. In case of the "Script Error" the extension (or browser) has not allowed you to access the debugging information, while the other extension (or browser) has allowed you to see it.

Most Client JS error tracking ignore "Script Error.". Read here

- https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/tips/
- http://blog.errorception.com/2012/03/tale-of-unfindable-js-error.html

Let's hope that this question finds popularity and we find the developer of the extension.